# error to install external plugin on ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to install a media player plugin using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/), but is returning the following error when i tried to compile and start it (`ionic serve -l`   ).

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(14,1): error TS1068:
>   Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected.
>
> [ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts(23,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

I did exactly as in the documentation but the error still here.

home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) { }


let options: StreamingMedia = {
  successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
  errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') },
  orientation: 'landscape',
  shouldAutoClose: true,
  controls: false
};
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    StreamingMedia,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

im forgetting something to start use this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4 changed some objects. You need to define this object (StreamingVideoOptions) for video. For example;

```
 myStreamVideoOptions :StreamingVideoOptions = {
successCallback: function() {
  console.log("Video was closed without error.");
},
errorCallback: function(errMsg) {
  console.log("Error! " + errMsg);
},
orientation: 'landscape',
shouldAutoClose: true,  // true(default)/false
controls: true // true(default)/false. Used to hide controls on fullscreen
```

};

and then you can use this it

```
let media: StreamingMedia = new StreamingMedia()
media.playVideo('my_video_url',this.myStreamVideoOptions)
```

So the full code in your example ;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  myStreamVideoOptions: StreamingVideoOptions = {
    successCallback: function () {
      console.log("Video was closed without error.");
    },
    errorCallback: function (errMsg) {
      console.log("Error! " + errMsg);
    },
    orientation: 'landscape',
    shouldAutoClose: true,  // true(default)/false
    controls: true // true(default)/false. Used to hide controls on fullscreen
  };

  constructor(private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) {

  }

  play(){
    let media: StreamingMedia = new StreamingMedia()
    media.playVideo('my_video_url',this.myStreamVideoOptions);
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you

Sorry for my bad english!